# "I want to spend the rest of my life with you" in French ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

> I want to spend the rest of my life with you ...

I am looking for a translation but not necessary a word by word.

I mean is : **Je veux terminer le restant de mes jours avec toi** fits here??

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use the verb "passer" instead of "terminer" here, i.e. "Je veux passer le restant de mes jours avec toi".

Comment: Your sugestion would be perfectly apropriate… for collective suicide. I guess you mean something else…

Comment: hahahaha thank you @StéphaneGimenez ... I meant je veux PASSER :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

> Je voudrais passer le restant de mes jours avec toi
>
> J'ai envie de passer le restant de mes jours avec toi

I'd avoid "je veux" as being too sharp, too imperative, and "terminer" because it references the end of life, which is not what you want for several different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

> Je veux passer le reste de mes jours avec toi.

You can go for "restant" instead of "reste", or "ma vie" instead of "mes jours", it doesn't change the meaning.

Of course "je veux" is sharp and imperative but so is "I want".

As the other posts say, "terminer" put an emphasis on the fact you want to be with the person when you will both die, which is not the important point here.

Answer (score 0):

In french, when you spend time, *on passe le temps*.

But when you spend money, energy and such, *on le dépense*

> Je veux passer le restant de mes jours avec toi.

Or

> Je veux passer ma vie avec toi

Answer (score 0):

" Je veux passer le reste de ma vie avec toi " (or " avec vous ").
It means: I love you SO MUCH that I really want to live with you till the end of my life (I have no doubt about it, so not something like "I would like to spend...").

I'm French.

Comment: Interprétation plus que réponse. [Suggested reading](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

> J'ai envie de passer le restant de mes jours avec toi.

Ton example signiferait se tuer ensemble... mdr

> Je veux passer le restant de mes jours avec toi.